# Pointer + Number

Tags: c++, c

I have this code:
How can i debug with printf?

```
char *string = "something";
short i;  

i = strlen(string);

while (i-- && (*(string+i)==' ' || *(string+i)=='\0'));

*(string+i+1) = '\0' ;
```

What does this do?

```
*(string+i)
```

Comment: `string` isn't initialized to anything? Your `strlen` is not safe.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. You can't modify a string literal. Use `const char *` or, better yet, `std::string`.

Comment: `*(array + i)` is just horrible style. Blame the author.

Comment: `a[b]` is a funny thing - it's equivalent to `*(a + b)` which is also equivalent to `b[a]` which is why you could also write `i[string]` instead of `string[i]`. slightly off-topic, but funny :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C standard, the expression `e1[e2]` is ***by definition*** equivalent to `*(e1+e2)`. So when you write

```
*(string + i)
```

it is equivalent

```
string[i]
```

This definition has an interesting side effect that it is actually correct to write `3[s]` instead of `s[3]` as operator [] is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

`*(string+i)` is `string[i]`. So `*(string+i) == '\0'` is the same as `string[i] == 0`.

This is because `pointer + number` is the same address as `pointer + number * sizeof(type)` (in your case `string + i` is the same a `string + i * sizeof(char)`. When you index into an array `arr[i]` is the element at address `arr + i * sizeof(type)`.

To debug with `printf` you simply insert `printf` statements and poke around the content of variables. For example:

```
char *string = "something";
short i;  
i = strlen(string);
printf("Debug i = %d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 1):

- The postfix operator -- means that `i` will get evaluated and then decremented before the next sequence point.
- The && operator has a sequence point between the left and right operand, so `i--` occurs before the right operand is evaluated.
- Therefore `string+i` refers to the value of the original i - 1.
- `*(string+i)` is guaranteed to be completely equivalent with `string[i]`. The former is just a less readable form.
- The code does a peculiar check. If a character is the null terminator, it adds another null terminator behind the first one. That doesn't make any sense. Only the check for space makes some sense.
- I also doubt the true intention is to add a null after the space? Wouldn't you rather want to remove the space and end the string there? Seems like a mistake.
- Also the code is inefficient, because if you count from the beginning to the end and encounter the first space there, you can stop iterating.

In other words, this code is just awful. You should replace it with something like this:

```
char* ptr = strchr(string, ' ');

if(ptr != NULL)
{
  *ptr = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Double nulls are sometimes used to pass several strings in one buffer. One null marks string separator, two mean end of the last one. Like `quick brown fox\0Lorem ipsum\0\0`.

Comment: The intent is probably to remove trailing spaces, not to clip the string at the first space.

Comment: @Agent_L That's odd. And in that case, the original code is broken anyway, since it doesn't replace the space with `\0`, but rather the symbol after it.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck I might actually have been fooled by not spotting the retarded semi colon at the end of the while loop. Ah well, the original code is broken beyond repair anyway... so lets just leave it at that.

Comment: I find it ugly but not broken, assuming `string` points to a modifiable string.

Comment: @Lundin yeah, I was just talking that double null might be meaningful in some very rare scenarios. The code looks like a specialized part of a greater whole. Eg. `i` is assumed to be greater than `strlen(string)`.